# Hiding the new Windows Terminal

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I used to hide my background app's console window until I needed it with

```
ShowWindow(console_hwnd,SW_HIDE);
```

My Windows got an update and switched to "Windows Terminal" as the default console app.
That line of code doesn't work anymore it just minimizes the console to taskbar. What is the proper way to fully hide Windows Terminal?

EDIT:
Please read the question carefully. It says HIDE the console window. NOT remove the console completely. I need to be able to show it again later. Thats the purpose of SW_HIDE and SW_SHOW that are no longer working with the new Windows Terminal.

Comment: that's not how it's supposed to work. To get a hidden app you need to compile it as [Windows subsystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=msvc-170), not console subsystem. Allocate a new console if you want, but the app needs to be GUI. Console apps can't be hidden, even in other OSes. They can only be moved to background

Comment: @phuclv then why does it work perfectly well with the classic windows console? I can hide it and when its time for me to display it again I call SW_SHOW and it appears again.

Comment: the old conhost.exe only allows a single process to attach, unlike modern terminals which allow multiple tabs. What will the behavior be? Hiding all or just a single tab? Either is non-sensible. Besides the old console API has been deprecated by MS, and they've moved to the common [ANSI sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) for better remoting experience and portability

Comment: in some previous documentation version MS said the console APIs have been deprecated and won't be updated in the future. But later when WriteConsole has been fixed to support UTF-8 support they removed the deprecation note, but still said [*For all new and ongoing development on Windows, virtual terminal sequences are recommended as the way of interacting with the terminal.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/classic-vs-vt)

Comment: there's no way to hide in all terminals. What if the user runs the app from VS code's terminal, xterm, cmder, conemu, tera term, mintty, putty...? conhost.exe isn't the only terminal out there, and not even the default terminal since Windows 11. Users can use any terminals they prefer, and if from an IDE they usually use the built-in terminal

Comment: Hi, Does this method meet your requirements?

Comment: @YujianYao-MSFT Does this work for you? I tried it it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hi, it works for me. Has the console's location changed from the default? If it changes but doesn't disappear from the screen, I suggest you try to modify the coordinates in [SetWindowPos()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos). Also I edited the answer, hope you could check it.

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Comment: The mention of terminal sequences is irrelevant as none of those relate to console window / tab visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the console at any time, you could hide and show the console by changing the coordinates of the console.

```
int main() {
  HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
  SetWindowPos(consoleWindow, 0, -600, -600, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow#parameters), the second parameter to `ShowWindow()` might get ignored the first time it is called. Try calling it twice.

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```

In addition, did you run this program as administrator? If so, I suggest you cancel it, since the window is in a higher privileged process, so your call will be ignored.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Calling `ShowWindow` twice does not work, and moving the window off-screen is an unsatisfactory hack because you'd have to inspect the coordinates of all attached monitors and calculate a new position that didn't overlap.